# Unable to send the large text using send_keys in selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web

I am trying to send some text to the text box. The problem is that when the text is short(small) it works, but when the text is long(big) it doesn't work. Please, I have pasted my code below. Let me know what I am doing wrong

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://editor.swagger.io/")


# when we read swagger file from excel will put it here

swagger = '{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"title":"test api *************************************}'

#fetch the box for the swagger input
editor = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ace_text-input")
#
# #clear it
editor.clear()
# #send the swagger we want to convert
editor.send_keys(swagger)```
````

Comment: While debugging what value you are seeing for swagger variable?

Comment: swagger is a string I created.  For example, if I use ```swagger = "This is the text"```, it works, but if I use ```swagger = "This is the text" * 10```, it doesn't work

Comment: Print `swagger = "This is the text" * 10` and see what is happening

Comment: maybe the text area is limited to some length of input string you exceeding?

Comment: No. I don't think that is the case. For example, try to copy the default text on the box (editor.swagger.io) and then save it as a string in the code. Then try to send it as a key so you can reproduce the exact problem